# Why not, how yarn log I can see?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

Starting yarn like `yarn start`, but log message is not present in console when pressing button.

[image]

Comment: check your browser console first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **client-side** JavaScript. It will log in the browser (specifically in the Console of the Developer Tools), not in the build tool chain (nor in the server started by the build tool chain).

Related: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the callback will be invoked when you click on the button in a browser.

You could see this log in a browser console.

In other words - this function won't be invoked while the yarn is compiling code